# What is the correct partition type for a geli-crypted partition on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, cryptography

I am currently in the process of setting up an encrypted homeserver with zfs and geli.
However I am not sure what the correct partition type for geli-crypted filesystems are.

Do I just take 'freebsd-zfs' like I would do for a noncrypted zfs partition?
Do I go with the more generic 'freebsd'?

All I want to know in the end is what value to pass as the '-t' parameter when calling 'gpart add'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of doubt, use `0xDA` (“raw / nōn-filesystem data”).

That will always work, and be ignored by virtuall all OSes, so geli can just use the corresponding block device.